# Meaning of asterisk in scanf format specifier?

Tags: c, string, input

What does
`scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s);` and
`scanf("%[^\n]", s);` mean?
What is the difference?

Comment: http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/R.Bowden/C/scanf.html

Comment: Please refer to the scanf documentation you used and point out the part in the description of the `*` which confuses you. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: For the same input, one reads `x` characters, the other reads `x + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the specifications for [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), in particular for the format specifiers.

The first statement, `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s);`, reads any characters into the variable called `s` of type `char*` until there is a newline character (`\n`) in the input. This newline character is *not* read and will remain in the input. It will append a null-terminator (`\0`) to the string read into `s`. This concludes the "string reading" part.
The function `scanf` will then read any character, which in this case must be the newline character, but will *not* assign its value to any variable as the asterisk (`*`) is the *"assignment-suppressing character *"*.

The second statement, `scanf("%[^\n]", s);`, is identical to the first, except that it will leave the newline character in the input.

Note that the standard warnings for using `scanf` apply here. This function is tricky to use safely. When reading a string, always include a maximum number of characters to read to avoid buffer overflow attacks. E.g. `scanf(%16[^\n]", s`. This will read a maximum of *15* characters, as it does not include the null-terminator.

Answer (score 0):

> `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s);`

means to scanf that the field length is provided by an extra parameter in the parameter list, just before the string, so to be correct, it should read as

```
void f(char *buffer, size_t buffer_sz)
{
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", buffer_sz, buffer);
}
```

(but I'm afraid that you are going to skip over anything that **is not** a `\n`, which probably is not what you wantk, I think that format is incorrect, as you didn't specify the main letter specifier)